# SavedModel usage is just for Tensor serving or to retrain

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

Is this [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) just for Tensorflow front-end applications or it can be use to reload model in keras format. I created it using `tf.saved_model.save` and now I don't know what to make of it.

Following the guide above I was able to load a `SavedModel` directory, and it seemingly no use, not trainable nor use to predict input like `model.predict`, and that the only thing I have since I lost the h5 file in my files **cough trashbin **cough.

**Note**: I noticed this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format) tell me to use `tf.keras.models.load_model('inceptionv3')`
and it return this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvAn0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have saved the model using `tf.saved_model.save` and so the correct way to load it back is `tf.saved_model.load('inceptionv3')`. This is also suggested in your error image.

After loading model, you can try doing prediction as follows:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('inceptionv3')
out = model(inputs)
```

Comment: Marked answer, however is this all it can do? can it be converted to something like keras model? Also, the SavedModel guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#general_fine-tuning) is telling something about finetuning, what is that about.

Comment: Yes model can saved as keras model.You can  search on Google to know more about it.